# How to change the appearance of time changing dynamically using javascript in following scenario?

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, timer

I'm using PHP, JavaScript, jQuery, Smarty, etc. for my website. I'm displaying time on a HTML file in Hr. Min. Sec. format. Actually, the time displayed is of a running test. It's displayed in countdown fashion. The time counter reduces the time dynamically(second by second) and ultimately reaches to zero(00:00:00). In short, the function is called recursively. The code for it as follows:

**HTML**

```
<body onLoad="load_timer('{$test_duration.hr}', '{$test_duration.min}', '{$test_duration.sec}', {$test_id}, '{$test_type}', '', '{$site_url});>
    <div id="test_time_left">Time Left :<b><span id="time_value" style="padding-left:5px;"></span> </b> </div>
</body>
```

N.B.: If you are not getting the parameters I'm passing to load_timer function, please ignore the syntax of smarty and consider all the parameters as normal parameters.

**JavaScript**

```
var hrs;
var mins
var secs;

function cd(hr, mi, se, test_id, test_type, test_pack_id, path) {
    hrs  = 1 * h(hr);
    mins = 1 * m(mi); // change minutes here
    secs = 0 + s(se); // change seconds here (always add an additional second to your total)
    redo(path, test_id, test_type, test_pack_id);
}

function h(obj) { 
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
        break;
    }
    return(obj.substring(0, i));
}

function m(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
        break;
    }
    return(obj.substring(0, i));
}

function s(obj) {
    for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
        if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) == ":")
        break;
    }
 return(obj.substring(0, i));
}

function display_time(hrs, mins, secs) {
    var disp;
    if(hrs <=9 ) {  
        disp = " 0";
    } else {
        disp = " ";
    }
    disp += hrs + " : ";

    if(mins <= 9) {
        disp += " 0";
    } else {
        disp += " ";
    }
    disp += mins + " : ";
    if(secs <= 9) {
        disp += "0" + secs;
    } else {
        disp += secs;
    }
    return(disp);
}

function redo(path, test_id, test_type, test_pack_id) { 
      secs--;
      if(secs == -1) {
        secs = 59;
        mins--;
            if(mins == -1) {
                mins = 59;
                hrs--;
          }
      }

    document.getElementById('time_value').innerHTML = display_time(hrs, mins, secs); // setup additional displays here.

    if((hrs == 0) && (mins == 0) && (secs == 0)) { 
      if(test_type=='public_test')
         window.location = path
      else    
        window.location = path+""+test_id+"/"+test_type+"/"+test_pack_id // redirects to specified page once timer ends and ok button is pressed
    } else {
        cd = setTimeout("redo('"+path+"', "+test_id +", '"+test_type+"', '"+test_pack_id+"')", 1000);
    }
}

function load_timer(hr, mins, secs, test_id, test_type, test_pack_id, path) {
 cd(hr, mins, secs, test_id, test_type, test_pack_id, path);
}
```

Till here everything is functioning perfectly. The issue I'm having is with the appearance of time I'm displaying.

Actually I want to display the time in values (in Hr: Min: Sec: values) in red color when the **remaining time is five minutes i.e. (from 00:05:59)**. Also the timer should get blink till it reaches zero (i.e. 00:00:00). How should I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understood your question right ...
Take a look at this jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/QLa8b/
I added 2 few lines, so that the minutes are displayed in red when they are lower or equal 5:

```
if(hrs == 0 && mins <= 5) disp += '<span style="color: red">';
...
if(hrs == 0 && mins <= 5) disp += '</span>';
```

You can do this with the other time values as well. I also added a blinking colon, but I think that's what you wanted to blink?

Comment: I was doing this, but you beat me to it. It's almost that. you can improve the fiddle a bit.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I need the whole timer(i.e. hr:min:sec altoghether) in red color and blinking. Now only the : after min is blinking and min is in red. Could you please correct your fiddle?

Comment: What if the remaining time is "01:04:30" ?? Will it blink too on a one hour+ remaining time ? Also, @PHPLover, you are already blinking the ":" symbol. Use the same mechanism to switch css classes `if(obj.substring(i, i + 1) $(#test_time_left).addClass("red") else $(#test_time_left).removeClass("red")`